# Android custom views: rotating wheel, "spinner" control

Tags: android, controls

Are there any existing implementations of rotating wheel, spinner like (not the actual android spinner) controls for Android?

Example:

[image]

Comment: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/534/android-ui-making-an-analog-rotary-knob/

Comment: look at this [link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/534/android-ui-making-an-analog-rotary-knob/) I think that this will sure help you

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are similar that you should be able to modify to your needs.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [Mind The Robot Analog Rotary Knob](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/534/android-ui-making-an-analog-rotary-knob/), which is a bit rough around the edges but you could use it as a base.

There's also a step-by-step walkthrough for creating a [Rotating Dialer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/), which again isn't exactly what you're after but could be modified further.

The last one might be the most promising, which is a [Rotary Knob Widget](http://go-lambda.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/rotary-knob-widget-on-android.html), the author states that the implementation could be useful as a volume control, which closely resembles your original picture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a totally awesome dial control for android https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hgdialrepo
It's well tested and very stable.
Here is the youtube demonstration: https://youtu.be/h_7VxrZ2W-g
The library comes is a demo app and source code.
Uses Canvas
Hope this helps.